# I'm trying to have my printf take formatting from inside my Char

Tags: c, csv, printf

I'm trying to print lines of a csv file but a few lines have a \n that i need to account for.

Example
"Deathtouch\nAfterlife 1 (When this creature dies, create a 1/1 white and black Spirit creature token with flying.)"

after Deathtouch there is a \n in it but when i use printf(%s\n, text) it prints the whole line. how would i have it take the \n in the char into account?

What I get:

Deathtouch\nAfterlife 1 (When this creature dies, create a 1/1 white and black Spirit creature token with flying.)

What i need:

Deathtouch

Afterlife 1 (When this creature dies, create a 1/1 white and black Spirit creature token with flying.)

Comment: You need to parse the input string, producing an output string with backslash escape sequences replaced with the corresponding characters. If you are careful, you can write the output in-place to the same buffer as the input because because the output will never be longer than the input.

Comment: how would i go about that?

Comment: A good place to start would be [strchr](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strchr.html) (single escape) or [strpbrk](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strpbrk.html) (multiple escapes.)